# How to identify and correct Bounding Box issues?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

Here is a simple offending [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxNWYwOFZGN0N5VzQ).

When I run [DrawPrintTextLocations](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.html) below is what I see..

[image]

But as far as I understand the bounding box(in blue above) should be representative of the grey area that shows up in any pdf reader when you select the text, like below.

[image]

If a pdf reader is able to figure out the grey area to show for highlighting, one should be able to figure out the same and thus get to the font size(?). This question is for anyone to point me in the right direction.

Following are the details of "T" in the text "Test Line." from its `TextPosition` object variable `text`:

```
72.4801          //text.getXDirAdj()
83.7600          //text.getYDirAdj()
1.0              //text.getFontSize()
50.0             //text.getFontSizeInPt()   ::I'm unable to decipher the 50.0
12.0             //text.getXScale()         ::Can I assume this to be the font size 
8.004            //text.getHeightDir()
7.8984           //text.getWidthOfSpace()
7.1160           //text.getWidthDirAdj()
950.0            //fontDesc.getAscent()
-222.0           //fontDesc.getDescent()
[x=72.4801,y=75.7560,w=7.1160,h=8.0040]
                 //Red Box boundaries
[x=72.4801,y=46.3560,w=7.1160,h=66.9600]    //The height of 66.96 relates to 50 but not sure how?
                 //Blue Bounding Box boundaries
```

**Questions:**
 1. *Bounding Box Issue:* Seems like this is not consistent when I call `font.getBoundingBox()`. Is there a work around for this?
 2. *getFontSizeInPts():* This method seems to be influenced by the bounding box. Am I right in thinking so?(As the Font Size in Pt is showing as 50)
 3. What is the way to get FontSize in points?

I need the font size as I have a task to recreate pdfs by using a different fonts.

*Also here is a case of the correct pdf but the font size shows up as 16 instead of 12 which was used initially.*

For similar [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxMFk4WWl4Ri1fak0) with proper bounding box, below are the details:-

*Output from [DrawPrintTextLocations](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.html) is*

[image]

Following are the details of "T" in the text "Test Line." from its `TextPosition` object variable `text`:

```
72.0605           //text.getXDirAdj()
83.3199           //text.getYDirAdj()
16.0              //text.getFontSize()      :: Why is this showing 16 while my font is 12 in size
16.0              //text.getFontSizeInPt()
12.0101           //text.getXScale()        ::Can I assume this to be the font size 
6.6618            //text.getHeightDir()
2.6447            //text.getWidthOfSpace()
7.1193            //text.getWidthDirAdj()
778.808           //fontDesc.getAscent()    :: There seems to be an issue with the ascent
-222.1680         //fontDesc.getDescent()
[x=72.0605,y=76.6581,w=7.1193,h=6.6618]
                  //Red Box boundaries
[x=72.0605,y=72.6176,w=7.1193,h=13.3237]    //The height of 13.3237 relates to 12 the font size but not sure how?
                  //Blue Bounding Box boundaries
```

*UPDATED AFTER USING MKL's ANSWER*
The below is what worked for me...

```
//Make Line
Line2D.Float line = new Line2D.Float(0,0,0,1f);
LOG.debug("Line<Before Transform>:" + line.getBounds2D());
s=myTextMatrix.createAffineTransform().createTransformedShape(line);
LOG.debug("Line after AT:"+s.getBounds2D());
s=pageFlipAffineTransform.createTransformedShape(s);
s=pageRotateAffineTransform.createTransformedShape(s);
rect2 = s.getBounds2D();
LOG.debug("Line<After Transform>:" + rect2);
//Font Size
double wi=rect2.getWidth();
double he=rect2.getHeight();
double total=Math.sqrt(wi*wi+he*he);//This is done in case of rotation
long fntSizeinPt = Math.round(total);
LOG.debug("deciphered Font Size is:" + fntSizeinPt);
```

Comment: Unlike you I get the overextended bounding boxes for both your example files. Which is no wonder as in both files the PDF font information claim a gigantic bounding box...

Comment: @mkl same behavior over here. Both fonts have the same gigantic bounding box. Edge for e.g. also uses this information for text selection. In our solutions we try to fix such situations by recreating the bounding box by analysing all glyphs bounding boxes. Anyhow e.g. Adobe Reader of Foxit seems to do this in another way as shown in the 2nd screenshot by bulbus.

Comment: @JanSlabon The OP claims both screen shots are created using the PDFBox `DrawPrintTextLocations` tool. I used that very tool but got gigantic bounding boxes for both PDFs.

Comment: @mkl apologies, I've updated the link with the correct pdf for second one now.

Comment: @bulbus I checked your third file, and indeed, the main font in there has a sensible **FontBBox** value; thus, you get mostly sensible blue boxes. A second font therein used for zero-width spaces is not quite as sensible and causes the blue pikes in the `DrawPrintTextLocations` outputs. I've extended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Bounding Box Issue: Seems like this is not consistent when I call `font.getBoundingBox()`. Is there a work around for this?

As already mentioned in a comment I could not exactly reproduce your observations as you described them: I get the overextended bounding boxes for the second PDF, too! And in both cases this is consistent with the font information in the PDF, the font descriptor **FontBBox** values are [-1475 -2463 2867 3117] and [-1474.60938 -2463.3789 2867.6758 3116.6992] respectively both of which are extremely large, the former seemingly a rounded version of the latter.

The third PDF you provided (and replaced the second with) uses two fonts. The one used for the actual "Test Line." characters has a font descriptor **FontBBox** value of [-19 -218 956 891] the values of which are more normal. As a consequence the blue frames drawn by `DrawPrintTextLocations` around those characters make more sense.  The second font has a somewhat large **FontBBox** value, [-1462 -813 1723 1134], and the result are the two blue lines exceeding the blue frames: The only character from that other font used are zero width spaces, so the boxes around them also have a zero width...

Thus, still everything is consistent.

A possible work-around would be not to trust the information from the PDF representation of the font but instead inspect the embedded font program

> 2. getFontSizeInPts(): This method seems to be influenced by the bounding box. Am I right in thinking so?(As the Font Size in Pt is showing as 50)

No. You must be aware that in PDFs the scale of drawn text depends on a number of items:

- First there is the "font size" you set together with the font using the **Tf** instruction;
- then there is the text matrix which can scale this size up or down;
- then there is the current transformation matrix which again can scale this size up or down;
- and finally there is the page **UserUnit** value which can again scale this size up.

In your first document you have a font size of **1** which the text matrix scales up to **50** and the current transformation matrix then scales down again to **12** which the **UserUnit** default value leaves as is.

In your second and third document you have a font size of **16** which the text matrix leaves as is and the current transformation matrix scales down to **12**, once again left as is by the **UserUnit** default.

The `FontSizeInPts` is a value you get after the second step (well, kind of, merely the top left entry of the text matrix is taken into account). As the situation in your documents shows, it essentially is a mere intermediate result of no further interest. Furthermore, the bounding box has not part in its calculation.

> 3. What is the way to get FontSize in points?

IMO you should take a vertical line as long as the font size value, apply the text matrix and the current transformation matrix, take the length of the resulting line and multiply that by the page **UserUnit** value.

The `TextMatrix` value of the `TextPosition` already combines a number of those steps; in spite of its name it is *not* the text matrix as specified in the PDF specification but more, cf. its documentation:

```
/**
 * The matrix containing the starting text position and scaling. Despite the name, it is not the
 * text matrix set by the "Tm" operator, it is really the effective text rendering matrix (which
 * is dependent on the current transformation matrix (set by the "cm" operator), the text matrix
 * (set by the "Tm" operator), the font size (set by the "Tf" operator) and the page cropbox).
 *
 * @return The Matrix containing the starting text position
 */
public Matrix getTextMatrix()
```

Thus, if `m` is that `Matrix`, you merely need to apply it to the points (0, 0) and (0, 1), apply the matrix to them, measure the distance of the resulting points, and multiply that distance by the page **UserUnit** value (which very often is `1`).

Comment: I've managed to implement what you recommended but I get fractional font Sizes like 9.75 for 10; 27.84 for 28;7.92 for 8 etc. Although am ok with the rounded font. Is my assumption that the pdf creator some how contracted the fonts for some reason ok?

Comment: *"I've managed to implement what you recommended but I get fractional font Sizes"* - I neither have your PDFs nor your actual implementation, so I cannot check whether there is some issue in PDFBox, in your implementation, or whether the font sizes in the PDFs actually are fractional, no matter what some PDF creators say. I would assume that it's the last option.

Comment: @bulbus *"can you point me in the right direction of **UserUnit**"* - Unfortunately `PDPage` does not have an explicit getter for that page dictionary entry. But for a `PDPage page` retrieving `page.getCOSObject().getFloat("UserUnit", 1f)` should do. (Most documents don't make use of the option to select the default user unit, so you will likely have a hard time finding a PDF for which this does not return 1...)